# JUnit Test Case Keeps Failing - toString

Tags: java, junit, tostring

Not quite sure why this is failing, worked fine on a previous class/test pair.

Test:

```
@Test
public void testToString() {
    OrderLine o = new OrderLine("Tuna 4 pack", 399 , 2);
    String toStr = o.toString();

    assertTrue("The toString method should be in the standard convention format", 
            toStr.startsWith("OrderLine:[") && 
            toStr.contains("=" + o.getId() + ", ") &&
            toStr.contains("=" + o.getUnitPrice() + ", ") &&
            toStr.endsWith("=" + o.getQuantity() + "]"));
}
```

Class Function:

```
public String toString()
{
    return ("OrderLine:[ ID = " + id +
            ", UnitPrice = " + unitPrice +
            ", Quantity = " + quantity + 
            "]");

}
```

Apologies if the answer to this is really obvious, its been grating me for some time and I don't exactly have any fellow students I can ask for help right now.

Comment: `toStr.contains("=" + o.getId() + ", ")` vs `= " + id +
            ",` - the string differs in the spaces...

Comment: you may rather use `assertEquals()` which will give you a popup with the actual differences in eclipse...

Comment: It's extremely obvious. Your toString() method returns each key/value pair with " = " between each key and its value, whereas your test is checking that "=" (without the spaces) is contained between each key and its value.

Comment: Thanks!

I had no idea that the spaces AFTER the equals mattered as my mind just seems to have read that they were irrelevant. I only put them there for the purpose of readability (my mistake I know) 

This is the rectified code o.O

    return ("OrderLine:[ID =" + id + 
   ", UnitPrice =" + unitPrice + 
   ", quantity =" + quantity + 
   "]");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

I had no idea that the spaces AFTER the equals mattered as my mind just seems to have read that they were irrelevant. I only put them there for the purpose of readability (my mistake I know)

This is the rectified code o.O

```
return ("OrderLine:[ID =" + id + 
        ", UnitPrice =" + unitPrice + 
        ", quantity =" + quantity + 
        "]");
```

Comment: You really don't want to have one space before and no space after the =. At least make it symmetric. I would suggest having spaces around it, and change your test method instead.